# error of Number of cross-validation runs must be equal for predictions and labels

Tags: r, prediction, roc

I am trying to get the best cutoff value.

Anyone knows why i can not use response to the type parameter in predict function here? i used type="response" to the same situation, except here i used cv.glm, but other situation is only glm.
[image]
[image]

Error in prediction(pred1, test$Survived) :   Number of cross-validation runs must be equal for predictions and labels.

It seems that the dimension of pred1 is different from test$Survived. Do i need to create a dataframe for test$Survived? if so, how should i create a dataframe correctly for this match?

dim(pred1) # returns 268   2
dim(test$Survived) # return NULL

Comment: Never post pictures, post code and data as text. We don't want to re-type your input!

Comment: sorry! formula <- as.factor(Survived) ~ Pclass + Sex + 
        Age + Fare + FS +
        Title + Embarked
train_control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10)
cv.glm <- train(formula, data=train, method="glm", 
                 family=binomial, trControl=train_control) # from caret library
library(ROCR)
pred1 <- predict(cv.glm, test,type = "prob")
predi <- prediction(pred1,test$Survived)
dim(pred1) #268   2
dim(test$Survived) # NULL